# Google Slides Linked Items

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, slide, google-slides-api

I'm trying to right a script that will loop through all linked items in a google slide and update then automatically at a given time.

I've managed to get this working for charts that I have linked from a spreadsheet, but can't seem to find a way to update anything else that I have linked.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I've just decide to add it as an iframe and then refresh the page every x amount of seconds.